# Do I need to retain the contextInfo for NSAlert alertDidEnd?

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, nsalert

I need to pass an `NSDictionary` with a couple of options to

`NSAlert - (void)beginSheetModalForWindow:(NSWindow *)window modalDelegate:(id)modalDelegate didEndSelector:(SEL)alertDidEndSelector contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo`

The docs don't say anything about if the `contextInfo` has to be retained or not. Right now I'm retaining it before showing the alert and releasing it in `alertDidEnd:`, but it would be nice to know for sure if that is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `contextInfo` is considered to be a "raw" C pointer (`void *`) and can be anything, it's your responsibility to manage memory (if you're passing an Objective-C object: to retain it).